# Some value return null on Dapper Multi Mapping

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper, multi-mapping

I'm having a problem using `Dapper`. 
I have a list of the `Rubrica` class that contains the field `valore`. 
When I run a query with a **JOIN** and identify the agenda type, the `valore` field remains set to `null`

My two classes `Rubrica` and `TipoAgenda`

```
public class Rubrica // Same as table anagrafico_rubrica
{
    public int id_rubrica { get; set; }
    public string cod_anagrafica { get; set; }
    public string descrizione_contatto { get; set; }
    public TipoRubrica tipo { get; set; }
    public string valore { get; set; }
}

public class TipoRubrica // Same as table anagrafico_tipo_rubrica
{
    public int id_tipo_rubrica { get; set; }
    public string descrizione_tipo_rubrica { get; set; }
}
```

I created a function that returns me a list of `Agenda` doing a **JOIN** with table `anagrafico_tipo_rubrica`

```
    public List<Rubrica> GetAgendaAnagrafico(string codiceAnagrafico)
    {
        using (DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection())
        {
            const string query = @"SELECT * FROM anagrafico_rubrica JOIN anagrafico_tipo_rubrica ON tipo = id_tipo_rubrica WHERE cod_anagrafica = @anagrafico";
            var parametri = new { anagrafico = codiceAnagrafico };
            return db.con.Query<Rubrica, TipoRubrica, Rubrica>(query, (rubrica, tipo) => { rubrica.tipo = tipo; return rubrica; }, parametri, splitOn: "tipo").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Here you can see what the query returns

[image: My result Query]

And here you see how int the `Agenda` list there is the value of `valore` set to `null`

[image: 'valore' have value null]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are splitting on `tipo`, which comes before `valore` in your query, so dapper is splitting the columns and thinking `valore` is for `TipoRubrica` instead of for `Rubrica`

Select the order of the fields explictly on your query

```
SELECT id_rubrica, 
       cod_anagrafica, 
       descrizione_contatto, 
       valore, 
       tipo,       // <-- you are splitting here. columns above are for 
                   //     first type, columns below for second
       id_tipo_rubrica, 
       descrizione_tipo_rubrica 
    FROM ...
```

So when you split on `tipo`, `valore` is before that, and it's mapped to the first type (`Rubrica`), instead of to the second (`TipoRubrica`)

Comment: Tried it, it works! I thought Dapper could understand which field automatically associate the values considering the name of the class.

Comment: By convention, it splits on `Id` fields, but if you are specifically telling it on which column to split on (on the parameter `splitOn: "tipo"`), it'll do as you command it to ;-)

Comment: Even if it was not the case, it's wise to (unless you have a very specific need not to) choose the fields you need on your queries explicitly, and not use `SELECT *` :-)

Comment: Yes, usually i select only the fields that interest me, but in this case they were all